# Replace CR2032 by li-ion reverse engineering

Tags: pcb-design, reverse-engineering, batteries

I want to replace my Wireless door bell by lithium-ion 3.3 V-4.2 V but I don't know if the circuit is design for that. It work with CR2032 3 V max.

I think I identified Attiny85 on the PCB, I can work up to 5 V. But I don't know if the 433 MHz circuit control by microcontroller can work with 4.3 V max.
Can you help me?

I know I can use LDO regulator (low quiescent) but I can avoid it?

Note: The li-ion battery will 3.9 V- 4.2 V because is charge by Solar.

Regards!

The circuit:
[image][image]

Comment: Added your images and fixed some of the language. Next time, please post in English.

Comment: Thanks for your fix. Sorry i'm french and my Android Keyboard have auto-corrected my text.

Answer (score 1):

It will probably work even with 4.2 V, but if you are cautious, you can use a 3 V LDO or stack two three Schottkys in series or one or two regular diodes to drop the voltage.

Comment: Thanks. "probably work" or "probably burn" ?  I already think about diode. And what about Zener Diode?

Comment: Adding an LDO will introduce power losses (even though the OP is adding a larger battery).  I'd bet the doorbell micro is in deep sleep all the time and only powers up when the button is pressed.

Comment: @JackCreasey Yes I also deduced that, the button is attached to PCINT0 of IC, it's like I was able to deduce that it was an attiny . This is what he embodies me with an ldo. Even if the ldo draw 5mA by hour about in 14 hours is total current draw is 70mA. I work with 500mA li-ion and the day the solar panel is recharge even cloudy day. But if  ldo draw 5mA it must the recharge is than > 5mA for compensate. Without regulator is far better.

Comment: @kiki67100 Like you say, the micro work up to 5 V and that's the majoriy of circuits. Sure, a ~1.2 V zener diode would do the job too.

Comment: I just purchase AP2127K-ADJTRG1 i choose the secure way.